# How to insert multiple foreign key values in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

i've tried using bulk_create but i couldn't insert the foreign key value, i want to add 100 bikes with about 20 stations

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    ID_Bike = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=120)
    Belong_Station = models.ForeignKey(
        Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='listBike')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ID_Bike

class Station(models.Model):
    name_Station = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=120)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_Station
```

Comment: It is not enterly clear what you aim to do, you only provide models here. What do you want to insert? Can you provide the current way you are insert the values?

Comment: for example i created 3 station A, B and C, and i want create Bike1 to Bike5 belong to station A, Bike6 to Bike10 belong to station B, and Bike11 to Bike 15 belong to station C. At the moment, i insert the data on the admin page of django, but it can only insert 1 bike at the time. So i want to insert 5 bikes for station A at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/). If I were you, I would stick with the SQL though. This is how an insert statement that will insert two Station and three Bike records could look like.

```
insert into Station (id, name_Station, latitude, longitude, address) values (1, "Johns Garage", 41.12, 23.58, "Fast Road 25, 001 12 Wales") , (2, "Mike riders place", 42.56, 21.43, "Somewhere street 12");

insert into Bike (ID_Bike, Belong_Station) values ("Johns bike", 1), ("Johns second bike", 1), ("Mikes bike", 2);
```

Notice that you must first insert Station records. Otherwise the foreign key constraint will fail if you try to insert Bikes first.